# HBox not showing up

Tags: java, css, layout, javafx

So, I can't seem to make the HBox show up in my application. The Button shows up, but the HBox does not. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
package cyanlauncher;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;


public class Main extends Application {
    private int numApps = 0;
    private float btnSize = 48;
    private float btnSpacing = 12;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            primaryStage.setTitle("CyanLauncher");

            Button quitBtn = new Button();

            Pane  root = new Pane();
            root.getChildren().add(addHBox());

            quitBtn.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("./../data/exit.png"))));
            quitBtn.setLayoutX(10 + ((btnSize + btnSpacing) * numApps));
            quitBtn.setLayoutY(7);
            quitBtn.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
            quitBtn.setPrefSize(btnSize, btnSize);
            quitBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            });

            root.getChildren().add(quitBtn);


            Scene scene = new Scene(root,64,64);


            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            scene.setFill(null);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    }

    public HBox addHBox() {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPrefSize(64, 64);
        hbox.setLayoutX(10);
        hbox.setLayoutY(7);  
        return hbox;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here is my CSS:

```
/* JavaFX CSS - Leave this comment until you have at least create one rule which uses -fx-Property */
.root {
     -fx-background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
}

.button {
     -fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}

.hbox {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HBox` has no style class by default (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#hbox)). So you need to do `hbox.getStyleClass().add("hbox")` in your (really badly named) `addHBox()` method.